# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : Running a package

Tags: java

I've been trying to compile a project containing 2 classes (can be more).
The two classes are in the same directory I'm working on.
I run the following command :

C:\Users\Me\Java>javac -d classes -cp classes *.java

The package files : cweek.java & nweek.java

```
package Hello;

public class cweek
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      nweek.printmeth();
   }
}
```

nweek.java

```
 package Hello;

    public class nweek 
    {
        public static void printmeth() 
        {
            System.out.println("I'm here");
        }

    }
```

Now I go to C:\Users\Me\Java\Classes\Hello and try to try "java cweek" command and I get the following error :

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cweek (wrong name: Hello/cweek)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run the class using fully-qualified class name, from the directory containing your package structure:

```
> C:\Users\Me\Java\Classes: java Hello.cweek
```

BTW, you have got your naming convention swapped. Package name should start with lowercase, and class name with upper case. So, it should have been - `hello.CWeek`

Answer (score 0):

cd to the directory where cweek.class file is located.
Run this command:

```
java Hello.cweek
```